# Sun-Java-6 Incorrect classpath/java.home problems in finding tools.jar

Tags: 11.04, configuration, java

I installed `sun-java6-jdk` and `sun-java6-jre` (and likely other related java6 packages such as fonts) for a project running on a Ubuntu 11.04 server distribution. Our project programmatically calls Javadoc from within our running executable. To do so, we obviously need to know the location of the tools.jar file which is part of the JDK distribution, but not the JRE distribution. The packages were installed into `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/` and there are bin and other directories under the two areas (JDK/JRE) which provide the various standard binaries.

Whenever we execute a java program (via the java binary), the internal java.home variable seems to overwrite any JAVA_HOME environment variable provided. We have concluded that the binary thus derives its java.home from the path of the binary. The java binary under the jdk really is a link to the jre version. Thus, no matter which one you 'execute', you are always getting the jre version, and thus the java.home directory is defined to be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre`.

As such, any running executable can not seem to find the `tools.jar` file, and even passing the `-cp /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jdk/lib/tools.jar` option does not help.  We're hoping that someone can help shed some light on how we can correctly access the `tools.jar` file enabling us to correctly be able to call the `com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute` method.

Example execution:

```
java -cp /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/lib/tools.jar -jar comtor.jar -sourcepath .

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javadoc/Main
    at comtor.Comtor.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's a hack, but we ended up copying the `tools.jar` file into the `jre/lib/ext` directory as if we were installing a 3rd party jar file as an extension.  This seems like an unnatural action and that we should be doing something on the command line via the `-cp` option (tried it and it failed), or through an environment variable (tried that too and it failed too).